# Capistrano deploy in multistage: Server error on staging scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

My problem is on staging environment. When i try to access my site throw this error:

```
  Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I understand this message as it tries to enter with production environment information.

I read many post about capistrano and multistages deployment. I should edit passenger configuration on virtual host (mod_rails).

The site is on shared server. I cannot edit passenger configuration and i need a quick solution.

Can i change RAILS_ENV for run the server on staging environment?

Thanks in advance. And excuse me to moderator. Now i can re post a question.
How could request that a question be deleted.

Comment: Re your question about how to get another post deleted, use the "flag" link which appears on the left, above this comment and below the tags to flag the question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error from the MySQL daemon.  You need to grant `user@localhost` the appropriate permissions in your MySQL DB, this is what I use:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, LOCK TABLES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INDEX, TRIGGER, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE ROUTINE ON your_database_name.* TO user@localhost;
```

Comment: Excuse. I was using this server and database with production configuration and works fine. Now i am using this server for staging. my prbblem is that the server continue running with production configurationn

Comment: My problem is RAILS_ENV. I can overwrite environment.rb in staging scenario. ADD this line ENV['rails_env'] = 'staging' or modify .htaccess with RailsEnv staging.